# graph in excel to represent correlation of 3 parameters

Tags: statistics, correlation

I have some data in excel and I would like to make a graphical representation of those data. Structure of my data:

persons ID : from 1 to 485
to every person, there is one parameter like average jumping distance
and another parameter (like height)
and finally there is a class to which every person belongs to (1, 2 or 3).

To assign persons to classes I have used k-means algorithm.

Now I would like to make a graph of this result. How can I do it please in excel (or by using another tool)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a simple scatterplot where the height is on the x-axis, the jumping distance is on the y-axis, and the 3 classes are identified by different symbols in the plot. You can easily build this plot by inserting three separate sets of data (one for each class) in the Excel graph.